# Fitting several columns inside of screen with jqGrid

Tags: jqgrid

I got jqGrid to work, sort of.  I have one table in particular that has several columns.  How can I get it to place all the columns onto the visible screen and allow for scrolling allong the x-axis?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a good Answer, and I hope to start a discussion about this, but this is what I did...

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
            tableToGrid("#table1", { shrinkToFit: false, width: 940 });
        });
```

Setting the width to a solid width seems to have solved the problem temporarily for now.  It will do.

**UPDATE: NEW PROBLEM**
Hey, for some reason, when I move this over to a production server, I am unable to change the width to the appropriate range.  Anyone know why that is?